# How to make a 360 panorama app using DJI Mobile SDK like DronePan?

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

I saw DronePan's app on Facebook recently. DronePan is a simple app to control DJI's Inspire 1 to take a cool 360 panorama, it's really awesome. You can check its video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZJImZhqcqE, so I am excited about it and want to make an iOS app like it too. I google it and figure out that DronePan is using DJI Mobile SDK to make the app. Now I am wondering if someone can give me some clues to start this project? Like using which API of the DJI SDK can I make the Inspire 1 to rotate the camera to take photos? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Good topic! The panorama feature is quite popular for the drones’  app recently. I just get started to play with DJI Mobile SDK for 2 weeks, google it and found [DJI SDK’s github page](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS). It’s really helpful for the starters like us. In the page, I found the [Creating a Panorama Application tutorial](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK/iOS-PanoramaDemo), I recommend you to check it! You can use 
DJI Mobile SDK’s Intelligent Navigation Waypoint missions and Joystick to control the aircraft’s camera to rotate and take photos. For the joystick feature, please check DJIGimbal.h file, there is a method called:

`-(void) setGimbalPitch:(DJIGimbalRotation)pitch Roll:(DJIGimbalRotation)roll Yaw:(DJIGimbalRotation)yaw withResult:(DJIExecuteResultBlock)block;`

By using it, you can send command to control the aircraft to rotate the gimbal manually. The tutorial also teach you how to stitch the photos you take and using OpenCV library to generate them into a panorama.

Hope this help!